# How to change headless from false to true ? [puppeteer]

Tags: puppeteer

How to change headless from false to true ?
How to hide browser?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(LOGIN_URL, { "waitUntil": "networkidle2" });
await page.evaluate((a) => {
   $('input[name="username"]').val(a.username)
   $('input[name="password"]').val(a.password)
}, {username, password})
 // I want to hide the browser
 // do something
await browser.close();
```

Comment: `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the browser turned headless mid-execution when it was started normally, or vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809241/can-the-browser-turned-headless-mid-execution-when-it-was-started-normally-or-v)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to hide the browser in puppeteer at runtime — that's because Chromium can be launched either headless or non-headless only.

But during one script you can first run non-headless browser, close it and then open headless:

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : false});
// 1. Enter requisites, log in to a site
// 2. Save cookies
await browser.close();
browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : true});
// 3. Load cookies
// 4. Go and do headless stuff
```

Comment: Relevant puppeteer methods: [page.cookies()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagecookiesurls) and [page.setCookie(...cookies)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies)

Comment: this solution is not working, Cookies is being set in `headless: false` mode only. But when we're trying to access the same cookies in `headless:true` model it's not working at all, getting just blank array, Reason is because `puppeteer` creates new profile each time we launch it

Comment: @AlokDeshwal could you create a new question with some sample code so we could debug it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});`

Comment: You are launching a new browser instance, with headless mode specified.

OP's asking how to hide the existing browser instance.

Like mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51853963/9802294), it's not possible