# Node.js Problem with puppeteer headless:True : " Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null"

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser

My code works perfectly well with headless false, but when I change it to true I get this error :

```
(node:92024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:7:17
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\wamp64\www\scrappingWithNodejs\testDiscordBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\wamp64\www\scrappingWithNodejs\testDiscordBot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)   
    at async getAllInfos (C:\wamp64\www\scrappingWithNodejs\testDiscordBot\index.js:28:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:92024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:92024) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My code :

```
async function getAllInfos() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }); 
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.goto(`https://www.japanread.cc/`, {
    waitUntil: ["load", "domcontentloaded", "networkidle0", "networkidle2"],
  }); //se rendre sur une page
    let trs = [];

    trs = tbody.querySelectorAll("tr");//the error is here
```

I tried to put showMo, put several things in the "waitUntil" but I get nothing, I really don't understand.
Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Try to make a screenshot of the page after opening it. Has your bot has been blocked by Cloudflare?

Comment: @Vaviloff thank you, I didn't think to make a screenshot, I have a cloudflare problem (Error 1020, Access denied). There is a way to pass it? because the script works when there is the window.

Comment: There isn't one simple solution — after all Cloudlfare's protection work correctly blocking bots and allowing people. You could start with trying to reuse cookies for the site you have in your browser now. See [this quesiton/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51853963/2715393)